# bug on multiprocessing with input?

Tags: python-3.x

the problem is:

when I run this code, by a unknow wey the input appears 4 times in the display after I put any number, strangely it also works if I insert again any number 4 times in a row, but my code wasn't supposed to work with one input?
if i do `target = (number)` it works great.

[click hero to see my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLVBR.png)

I have 2 files.

saving_numbers.py:

(it calculates pair, odd, prime and all numbers)

```
def pair(number, target):
    while number != target:
      number +=1
      if number % 2 == 0:
       text_file = open("perrrrfect.txt", "a")
       text_file.write (str(number)+' divided by /2 remain 0 \n')
       text_file.close()

    def odd(number, target):
      while number != target:
       number +=1
       if number % 3 == 0:
        text_file = open("broken.txt", "a")
        text_file.write (str(number)+' dividided by /3 remain 0 \n')
        text_file.close()

    def prime(number, target):
      while number != target:
       number +=1
       if number > 1:
        for i in range(2,number):
           if (number % i) == 0:
               break
        else:
         text_file = open("primari numbers.txt", "a")
         text_file.write (str(number)+' it is primary \n')
         text_file.close()

    def numbers(number, target):
      while number != target:
       number +=1
       text_file = open("all.txt", "a")
       text_file.write (str(number)+'\n')
       text_file.close()
       print ('just more ',target-number,' to go!\n'+
            'be patient, render a big number one by one is hard')
```

and starter who make the magic happen

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from saving_numbers import *

def start():
   while True:
    try:
      target = int(input('enter a number to calculate the odds, pairs, and primary numbers\n: '))
      number = 0
      processes(number, target)
      break
    except:
      print ('must be numbers!')

def processes(number, target):
   if __name__ == "__main__":

     arr1 = target
     arr2 = number

     p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=pair,args=(arr2,arr1))
     p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=odd,args=(arr2,arr1))
     p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=prime,args=(arr2,arr1))
     p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=numbers,args=(arr2,arr1))

     p1.start()
     p2.start()
     p3.start()
     p4.start()

     p1.join()
     p2.join()
     p3.join()
     p4.join()

start()
```

Comment: Is your question why the input appears 4 times or why it works with the same input 4 times?

Comment: why it appears 4 times and why it works if i awnser the 4 extra inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to change from `import multiprocessing` to `from Treading import Thread`

AND change the remaining to:

```
while True:
try:
  targett = int(input('enter a number to we separate pairs,odds and primes: '))
  number = 0
  break
except:
  print ('must be numbers!')

def processes(number, targett):
 arr1 = targett
 arr2 = number

 p1 = Thread(target=pair,args=(arr2,arr1,))
 p2 = Thread(target=odd,args=(arr2,arr1,))
 p3 = Thread(target=prime,args=(arr2,arr1,))
 p4 = Thread(target=numbers,args=(arr2,arr1,))

 p1.start()
 p2.start()
 p3.start()
 p4.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  processes(number, targett)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this code block:

```
 p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=pair,args=(arr2,arr1))
 p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=odd,args=(arr2,arr1))
 p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=prime,args=(arr2,arr1))
 p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=numbers,args=(arr2,arr1))

 p1.start()
 p2.start()
 p3.start()
 p4.start()

 p1.join()
 p2.join()
 p3.join()
 p4.join()
```

You first create four processes correctly, and then you start each of the processes. They are started asynchronously, so it does not block execution to wait for the `start()` function to execute before calling `start()` on the next process. So it's not going to wait for you to answer the input before moving on to the next one. Therefore you can answer the input four times for each of the four times you called start.

Comment: i edited my question, please re-read it you must be confused (just see the "click here to see my issue")